# Wordpress text editor tags does not work, what do I need to change?

Tags: html, wordpress

As the title suggest, when using wordpress the html editor has the following tags:

[image]

I tried using the ul tag and li tags with content but on the published page, shows it all in a single paragraph tag using chrome inspect element.

I believe this should be a setting in wordpress but for the life of me I cannot find anything related to it.

Which setting needs to be adjusted to correct this issue?

P.S. the wordpress was not a clean install, it came from a live site where the html tags does not get stripped. And this issue only happens with pages but not posts.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I updated the wordpress installation and the issue still didn't get resolved. It seems I will have to use posts as pages for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your website http://dev.wlh.co.za/ and there is some CSS code that prevents it to render as you expect. It's not a problem with Wordpress, but you theme or a plugin.

I found this line many times in code, this stops the browser to render a UL or OL as usual:

```
list-style: none;
```

Another one you should fix is

```
padding: 0;
```

Have look on this example:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I updated the wordpress installation and the issue still didn't get resolved.